# MOODLE JSON file to direct email to specific region

Tags: javascript, json, moodle

I have 5 regions: Region1, Region2, Region3, Region4, Region5.
Within each region is a number of Proctors (for testing): For Region1 -- Mary, Jack, and Mark

When a student takes a test, a generated email is sent to all the Proctors in that Region. This is currently handled by a JSON file. I'd like for it to be handled by a table in the database. Here is the code related to gathering the information from the JSON file:

```
  function get_region_proctors($region) {
    global $CFG;
    $rval = array();
    $json_raw = file_get_contents($CFG->dirroot . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'jca' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.json');
    if (empty($json_raw)) {
      throw new Exception("Unable to get json from data.json");
    }
    $json_data = json_decode($json_raw);
    foreach($json_data->proctors as $p) {
      if ($p->region == $region) {
        $rval[] = $p;
     }
    }
    return $rval;
  }
```

Here is what the JSON file looks like:

```
{
"proctors" : [
{
"region" : "Region1",
"name" : "Mary Edwards",
"email" : "medwards@example.com"
},
{
"region" : "Region1",
"name" : "Jack Phillips",
"email" : "jphillips@example.com"
},
{
"region" : "Region1",
"name" : "Mark Jensen",
"email" : "mjensen@example.com"
}
]
}
```

The question is: how do I get the code to look at a database (array) instead of the DATA.JSON file?

**EDIT:**

After I used the code suggested below, I found that when I went to view or edit the Proctor list there was a javascript file that seems to do the following:

Once a Proctor is chosen, the javascript automatically sets the Region. Here's the script (I am not a javascript pro):

```
var proctors = [];

$(function () {
  //disable region sel as proctor sel will control
  $('#id_profile_field_Region').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#mform1').submit(function () {
    //need to reenable so php will note changes
    $('#id_profile_field_Region').attr('disabled', false);
  })
  $.getJSON('../jca/data.json', function(json) {
    proctors = json.proctors;
  }).error(function() { alert("There was an error loading json. "); });
  $('#id_profile_field_Proctor').change(function () {
    newProctorSelected($(this).find("option:selected").text());
  })
});


function newProctorSelected(pName) {
  //find proctor object from json
  var p = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < proctors.length; i++) {
    if (proctors[i].name === pName) {
      p = proctors[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (p) {
    //set the value of region based on region name of proctor
    $('#id_profile_field_Region option').each(function() {
      if($(this).text() === p.region) {
        this.selected = true;
        return;
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    alert("proctor not found");
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error message "There was an error loading JSON". Is there a way to replicate this function in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table called mdl_local_proctors with id, region, name, email

Then just use

```
function get_region_proctors($region) {
    global $DB;

    return $DB->get_records('local_proctors', array('region' =>  $region));
}
```